# ...where he sang in the boy/boy's/boys/boys' choir

Tags: word-choice

> He went to a catholic boarding school where he sang the
> boy/boy's/boys/boys' choir.

Hi. Which of these is correct?

Comment: I sing in a men's chorus.  The attribute is both plural and possessive.  By analogy, it should have to be **boys'** choir, where the **s'** indicates both plural and possessive.

Comment: You went to a Catholic boarding school (capital C), short for Roman Catholic, rather than catholic.   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catholic

Comment: ...sang **in** the boys' choir.

Answer (score 3):

The Philadelphia Boys Choir & Chorale https://phillyboyschoir.org/

but boys' choir in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boys%27_choir

Other links from the search for "boys choir" suggest that it's
"A Particular Boys Choir" but "a generic boys' choir".

So in your example, "boys'" to show that the choir happened to consist of boys. You would say "the St Sebastion Boys Choir".

Comment: Surely: **The St Sebastion Boys' Choir** and **The Philadelphia Boys' Choir** with apostrophe

Comment: @RonaldSole  The Phildelphia  Boys Choir names itself without an apostrophe. So do most boys' choirs I find on the internet.

Comment: I'll leave my query in place anyhow, lest any other pedantic souls should make the same comment. I am aware that many institutions have wrestled with the apostrophe conundrum.